# Style Does Not Work in ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, visualization, style

The documentation indicates simple, consistent, and intuitive usage for wrappers in `ListLinePlot` and `ListLinePlot3D`. However, the `Style` wrapper for `ListLinePlot` doesn't seem to work.

For example, consider the examples below. The `Labeled` wrapper works as the documentation indicates, the same way for `ListLinePlot` and `ListLinePlot3D`, and how you would expect (examples 1 and 2). The `Style` wrapper works this way for `ListLinePlot3d` (example 3) but not for `ListLinePlot` (example 4).

Can I fix this or get around it? I would like to stylize individual points in `ListLinePlot`.

### 1 ) ListLinePlot3D with Labeled (ok)

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, Labeled[2.9, "hello"], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 
   1.1, 2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.03}]
```

[image: 1]

### 2 ) ListLinePlot with Labeled (ok)

```
ListLinePlot[{{2.1, Labeled[2.9, "hello"], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 
   2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.05}]
```

[image: 2]

### 3 ) ListLinePlot3D with Style (ok)

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, Style[2.9, Red], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 
   2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.03}]
```

[image: 3]

### 4 ) ListLinePlot with Style (broken)

```
ListLinePlot[{{2.1, Style[2.9, Red], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 
   2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.05}]
```

[image: 4]

---

- Mathematica Version 13.0.1.0
- macOS Big Sur Version 11.6.5

Comment: Repeatable in Mma 13.0.1 on Win 10 Pro.

Comment: Just to play Devil's Advocate, I wonder if `ListLinePlot3D` is doing something that it shouldn't be doing.  In the manual for both `ListLinePlot` and `ListLinePlot3D` `Style` is applied to a complete dataset rather than an individual data point.  Also, when `Style` is applied to a dataset in `ListLinePlot`, it is the line that is modified and not the plot marker.

Comment: @JimB It seems unlikely to me `ListLinePlot3D`'s (arguably expected) feature is a bug and `Style` not working on points for `ListLinePlot` is intended behavior, considering it is unnecessarily restrictive. All other wrappers I've tested work as expected. Only `Style`, only for `ListLinePlot`, only for points, is the exception.

Comment: Outliers are in the eyes of the beholder.  But my point is that I'm not seeing in the documentation that `Style` should work on an individual point.  Doing so would be a nice feature but it's not clear to me that it has been advertised as such.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is not possible in a ListLinePlot. The only solution is with "Epilog"

Regards,....Jos

> ListLinePlot[{{2.1, 2.9, 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 2.2}, {2.3, 1.7,
> 2.3, 1.7}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.05},
> Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{{2.0, 2.9}}]}]